# Java Play Framework - Heroku: No such file app crash

Tags: java, heroku, playframework, crash

> "bash: target/universal/stage/bin/play-java-starter-example: No such
>   file or directory"

I grabbed the latest starter example from the **Java Play Framework** website. I added a Procfile with the following line:

```
web: target/universal/stage/bin/play-java-starter-example Dhttp.port=${PORT} ${JAVA_OPTS} -DapplyEvolutions.default=true -Ddb.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver -Ddb.default.url=${DATABASE_URL}

web: target/universal/stage/bin/play-java-starter-example Dhttp.port=${PORT}

web: target/universal/stage/bin/play-java-starter-example
```

I tried all variations of this line. It all builds and pushes successfully to master, but when I look at the logs, it shows that it cannot find the file in the directory. When I try to run the app, it crashes immediately. I checked in my files, this is the correct name of the file and it does exist. I have looked into multiple issues related to this on here, but all of them seem to be caused by a misnamed file or not cleaned project. I have checked both.

Help.

Comment: code and error are now formated

Comment: I suppose it works locally? Did you make sure that all files in `target/universal/stage` are committed and pushed to Heroku?